# Rails 4 routing helper generating unexpected paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a Rails 4 application which has the following code snippets:

`config/routes.rb`

```
concern :messageable do
  resources :messages, only: [:create, :destroy]
end

namespace :recruiter do
  resources :applications, only: :show, concerns: :messageable
end
```

In a particular view `companies/application/_messages.html.erb` (`CompaniesController` with `application` acting as a partials folder - The `application` variable used here is passed using `locals`)

```
<%= form_for [current_recruiter, application, Message.new], remote: true do |f| %>
```

generates

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/recruiter/applications/4/messages" class="new_message" data-remote="true" id="new_message" method="post">
```

Again

```
<%= form_for recruiter_application_messages_path(application.id), remote: true do |f| %>
```

generates

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/companies/2" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

For the record, I feel that the "4" in `/recruiter/applications/4/messages` is being taken from the value of `current_recruiter.id`. What I am looking for instead is the value of `application.id` (in a particular case, 16) in that placeholder. Could anyone help me with debugging this route helper?

Relevant Output of `rake routes`:

```
recruiter_application_messages POST   /recruiter/applications/:application_id/messages(.:format)     recruiter/messages#create
recruiter_application_message DELETE /recruiter/applications/:application_id/messages/:id(.:format) recruiter/messages#destroy
```

Comment: This looks totally fine to me. What do you expect the routes to look like?

Comment: Since the `application.id` is 16, I would like 16 in place of 4, the recruiter-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking of adding this as a comment but since it's a bit long, I hope it's fine to place this as an answer.

Your first `form_for` looks like

```
form_for [current_recruiter, application, Message.new], remote: true do |f|
```

I am assuming that `current_recruiter` is an `ActiveRecord` object so this translates to `recruiter_application_path` which conflicts with the defined route.  I've made some experiment using the same code in an existing project. In the console, I ran the following

```
>> app.recruiter_application_messages_path(1)
=> "/recruiter/applications/1/messages"

>> app.recruiter_application_messages_path(1, 2)
=> "/recruiter/applications/1/messages.2"

>> app.recruiter_application_messages_path(1, Application.new)
=> "/recruiter/applications/1/messages"
```

So my guess is that there's a route conflict here and `application` is a new object.  It's a lot of ifs but I think that's your current scenario.  In order to use the route declared with a namespace, make sure that `application` is a persisted object and change the `form_for` to

```
form_for [:recruiter, application, Message.new], remote: true do |f|
```

For the second `form_for`, I think you just forgot to pass the first argument which is the new message object

```
form_for Message.new, url: recruiter_application_messages_path(application.id)
```

Comment: I will accept the first variation of your answer. That is exactly what I was looking for. If possible, could you explain why `:recruiter` works and not `current_recruiter`. For confirming some of your assumptions, `application` is not a new object but a persistent object, and `current_recruiter` is an ActiveRecord object available using the `devise` gem.

Comment: I can't find any documentation about this but `[object1, object2, object3]` translates to `object1_object2_object3_path`.  knowing this, your array translates to `recruiter_application_messages_path`.  By default, you'd assume that this route requires a recruiter as the first argument, and application as the second argument.  Since the route you want to match only needs application as the argument, you don't need to pass the recruiter.  In order to get the named_route you want, you need to just change `current_recruiter` to `:recruiter`.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the documentation in Rails guides. It has to do with the fact that :recruiter is a namespace. Here's the link for your reference. :)
Section 2.3.1 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html